# recode values into one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with one value per row, potentially in one of several columns. How can I create a single column that contains the column number the 1 is in? I would like to do this using dplyr, but the only methods I can think of involve for loops, which seems very not R like.

```
df<-data.frame(
  a=c(1,0,0,0),
  b=c(0,1,1,0),
  c=c(0,0,0,1)
)

  a b c
1 1 0 0
2 0 1 0
3 0 1 0
4 0 0 1
```

GOAL:

```
1 1
2 2
3 2
4 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for *dplyr* here.  This is what `max.col()` is for.  Since all the other values in the row will be zero, then `max.col()` will give us the column number where the 1 appears.

```
max.col(df)
# [1] 1 2 2 3
```

If you need a column, then

```
data.frame(x = max.col(df))
#   x
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 2
# 4 3
```

Or `cbind()` or `matrix()` for a matrix.

Comment: Awesome thanks. When I saw your first post I used: `matrix(max.col(df),ncol=1)`

Answer (score 1):

We could also do

```
as.matrix(df) %*%seq_along(df)
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    2
#[3,]    2
#[4,]    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
which(df==1, arr.ind=T)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   1
# [2,]   2   2
# [3,]   3   2
# [4,]   4   3
```